# How to square ImageBackground depending on display dimensions?

Tags: react-native, imagebackground

I want to square the background Image like for example

height : 200,
width : 200,

But then also I want to change the size depending on the display size like:

width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.5
height: 'auto'

How can I do this?

set height to 'auto' does not work. Also I played with resizeMode

This are the style props:

```
  backgroundImageStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    top: 100,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    position: 'absolute'
  },
```

Comment: yes exactly. Just not a fixed size

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `backgroundImageStyle` as default styling option, but I would recommend using resizeMode "contain". In your render method you can override your height/width with:

```
<Image source={{YOUR_IMAGE_URI}} 
style={[styles.backgroundImageStyle, {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').width}]}
/>
```

**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/S15hYZVAN

**Output:**

[image: example]

**Edit:**

If you don't want to have the full size, you can scale down the image by dividing the width by a factor as shown below:

```
<Image source={{YOUR_IMAGE_URI}} 
style={[styles.backgroundImageStyle, {width: Dimensions.get('window').width/2.5, height: Dimensions.get('window').width/2.5}]}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I don't want to show the picture in full size. Is it possible to make it smaller but still a square or do I have to edit it manually with photoshop and then just load the full image?

Comment: @user9468014 you can divide the width by a factor like you did in your question, that's not a problem. I've updated my answer to show you how it works